# random/sequential numbers in JQ (or workaround)

Tags: random, jq

IIUC jq does not support random numbers at the moment. I have script producing lines, where each line is JSON. I need to pipe it to jq to transform the data, and output pipe yet further. The problem is, that I need as a part of jq transformation to set some field to some random/sequential value. And since the jq is invoked just once and processes streamed data, I cannot supply random value from bash, as it would be not random, but always the same.

Is there a workaround/solution for this?

Comment: maybe I could use some constant in place of random value, and then replace externally, but if I pipe jq output even to: `while read R;do ...;done` then the data are available only after whole input is processed, which is not possible, every line has to be processed asap. Maybe this is just a incorrect bash usage? If so, do you know how to fix that? EDIT: ok, so that is solved by --unbuffered parameter. So this is one workaroudnd. If you know better, please share.

**example of invocation of my nasty workaround:**

```
cat | jq --unbuffered -c '.random="PLACEHOLDER"' | while read R; do echo $R | sed "s/PLACEHOLDER/$RANDOM/";done | sed "s/^/anotherScriptMock/"
```

and start entering valid jsons like `{}`

Comment: How many values would you expect to insert? How many within a singe result? Are you inserting random numbers? Words? etc... Could you provide a more representative example of some inputs and outputs?

Comment: at the moment it's like 2-3 per json of fixed format, but theoretically it can be arbitrary, depending JSON. Number of jsons depends on the length of testing session and json generation speed. Quality of random numbers isn't important, as I just trying to hack my way through some temporary testing scenario where this could help me. We can assume that only strings containing numbers will be inserted(since --arg passes value as string and $RANDOM generates number), and where it's not the case, I suppose I can fix it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot supply random value from bash, as it would be not random, but always the same.

That is a bit harsh.  The wikipedia article ["List of random number generators"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators) has two sections that give relevant listings:

- Random number generators that use external entropy
- Random number servers

If your requirements are not too stringent, you might find that several of these are sufficient for your purposes.  On a Linux or OSX system you might like to start with [/dev/random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random), e.g. in conjunction with [od](/questions/tagged/od) or GNU shuf (sometimes available as gshuf):

```
shuf -i 0-1000 -n 1 --random-source=/dev/random
```

(You will probably want to use -r ("with replacement") if the value following -n is greater than 1.)

If you don't mind a web-based server, https://www.random.org/ has a bunch of services, e.g. you could start with this template:

```
jq -n --argjson r $(curl -Ss "https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=0&max=100000&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new") '
  {random: $r}'
```

Running this just now produced:

```
{
  "random": 41051
}
```

And running the exact same program a second time produced:

```
{
  "random": 7358
}
```

### Example: .range=PLACEHOLDER

Suppose the file data.json contains a stream of JSON objects:

```
{}
{}
{}
```

Then a run of the following bash commands produced the output as shown below:

```
n=$(stream | jq -n 'reduce inputs as $x (0; .+1)')
gshuf -i 0-100 -r -n $n --random-source=/dev/random | 
  jq -cnR --slurpfile stream data.json '$stream[] | .random=input'
```

Output:

```
{"random":"17"}
{"random":"69"}
{"random":"81"}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing nice examples, I did not know to use `--random-source`, but the question asked about situation, where jq is in the middle of piped chain, it processing streams of data, while your example uses just 1 invocation. If I use this, all jSONS will have same "random" value.

Comment: You clearly misunderstood my responses.  You can for example pass in as many random numbers as needed to each invocation of jq, or (as shown in my other response), you can pipe in an unboundedly long stream to each invocation.  You can use the same techniques if you want to invoke jq many times, though that may not be necessary.  Without knowing more about the actual problems you're trying to solve, it's hard to be clearer.

Comment: yes I don't understand it. I posted an working nasty workaround I was able to come up with. There will be just 1 invocation of JQ, which will process streaming data. For how long? I don't know. For how many records? I don't know. 5? 5 millions? Maybe. So generating sufficiently big array of random numbers beforehand is not especially healthy solution either; but since I still don't know how to handle global variables in jq I'm not sure how I'd use it. But maybe I could have as a part of transformation doing slices of this hell of an array, could work. Anyways IIUC that wouldn't be optimal

Comment: argh. Sorry. I somehow overlooked, that I can put jq inside of while loop. Sorry. Is that what you meant?

Comment: In some circumstances, it might make sense to put jq inside a while loop, but in general, it would be better to avoid doing so.  If you want to feed jq an unbounded stream of random numbers, then please see my other response using `input`, but there are other alternatives. The details will of course depend on your specific needs.

Comment: thanks, I'm trying to understand this answer (which I don't at the moment) but my bash skill are probably lagging little bit anyways, and cannot find a solution to this — if I already have input I need to pipe into JQ, how do I pipe in this random numbers stream? If we need to talk about specific usecase, lets talk about one I posted as a sample, it should be sufficient to demonstrate this and I have no idea how to rewrite.

Comment: Please see the added "Example" sections in both my answers.

Answer (score 2):

Generating a fixed number of (sufficiently) random numbers to serve as input to jq is dealt with elsewhere on this page.  This response deals with the case when the jq program must have access to an unbounded ("infinite") sequence of such numbers.

Consider then this generator of an unbounded sequence of strings of "random" hexadecimal digits of length 8:

```
od -t x -An /dev/random | tr -d " " | fold -w 8
```

(On many systems, this produces a cryptographically secure stream.)

There are several ways to feed this into jq.  One is simply to use `input`, e.g.

```
od -t x -An /dev/random | tr -d " " | fold -w 8 |
 jq -nRc '[range(0;5) | input]'
```

produced:

```
["54a4bdb9","13b6ed75","86bbe494","79b192f5","43f801c8"]
```

If the task of the jq program is to produce an unbounded stream of such quintuplets, consider this variation:

```
od -t x -An /dev/random | tr -d " " | fold -w 8 |
  jq -nRc 'repeat( [limit(5;inputs)] )'
```

### Example: .random = PLACEHOLDER

Using the same data.json as shown elsewhere on this page, a run of the following bash commands produced the output shown below:

```
od -t x -An /dev/random | tr -d " " | fold -w 8 |
  jq -nRc --slurpfile stream data.json '$stream[] | .random=input'
```

Output:

```
{"random":"79c434e6"}
{"random":"28797cf9"}
{"random":"90a8813d"}
```

Comment: You could simplify significantly using the `-w` and `-N` switches to limit the amount of bytes are displayed on a line and how much is read overall. e.g., `od -An -tx4 -w20 -N20 /dev/random | jq -R 'split(" ")[1:]'`

Comment: @JeffMercado - I just wanted to show how one can create a pipeline beginning with an unboundedly long stream, without the need for any parsing of that stream on the jq side. Given those two goals, what improvement would you propose?

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, we focus on the `.random = PLACEHOLDER` example given in the Q, and assume that the input stream of objects is infinite, or too long or too large to "slurp" (e.g. using --slurpfile).

In order to avoid calling jq more than once (or twice if the input stream is NOT presented in JSONLines format), we will have to generate the random numbers on demand, i.e. in a loop.

Assuming that `stream` generates the (possibly infinite) stream of JSON objects of interest in JSONLines format (as posited by the Q), we can write:

```
stream | while read -r obj ; do
    echo "$obj"
    gshuf -i 0-100 -n 1 --random-source=/dev/random
done | jq -nc 'repeat(input |  (.random = input))?'
```

(To test this, one could replace `stream` by `jq -n 'repeat({})'`, which generates an unbounded stream of empty JSON objects.)

The trick here is to use `?` to avoid raising an "end of stream" error in case the `stream` stream is finite.

If `stream` does not produce the JSON objects in JSONLines format, then one could replace `stream` by `stream | jq --unbuffered -c .`, which of course means that the solution requires invoking jq twice.

Answer (score 0):

`jq` can generate pseudo-random numbers if *one* initial random number is provided (`--argjson initialRandomNumber`).

I used a slightly modified version of the function `nextRandomNumber` from Rosettacode [jq: random numbers](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Random_numbers#jq) to generate pseudo-random numbers as shown in the following code.

The function takes a parameter `$state` and delivers a `newState` in the response for a subsequent call of `nextRandomNumber`.

If a number in the range [0 .. 32767] is not sufficient, you can have a look at [jq : Generate UUID in field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61842926/jq-generate-uuid-in-field/68192205#68192205) where I added a small collection of random functions for `jq` to generate UUID, random string, random numbers and arrays of these.

Passing `$RANDOM$RANDOM` instead of `$RANDOM` is intended to increase the range for the initial pseudo-random value.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

jq -n '{id: (range(10) + 1)}' |   # create stream of json
jq -n --argjson initialRandomNumber "$RANDOM$RANDOM" '
  # 15-bit integers generated using the same formula as rand() from the Microsoft C Runtime.
  # The random numbers are in [0 -- 32767] inclusive.
  #
  # Input: 
  #   first call:      $state = a random number provided to jq by parameter
  #   subsequent call: $state = "newState" from last response
  #
  # Output: 
  #   object with pseudo-random number and "newState" for a subsequent call.
  def nextRandomNumber($state):
    ( (214013 * $state) + 2531011) % 2147483648 # mod 2^31
    | { newState: ., randomNumber: (. / 65536 | floor) };

  foreach inputs as $input (nextRandomNumber($initialRandomNumber); 
                            nextRandomNumber(.newState); 
                            $input + {randomNumber})
'
```

### output

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "randomNumber": 24271
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "randomNumber": 5840
}
{
  "id": 3,
  "randomNumber": 3059
}

(...)

{
  "id": 10,
  "randomNumber": 24864
}
```